# Scope of Nested Classes

Tags: c#

If I have a nested class, does anything from the owning class exist in the owned class?

for example:

```
public class OwningClass 
{

    int randomVariable = 1;

    public void MakingMethod()
    {
        OwnedClass owned = new OwnedClass();
        owned.SomeMethod();
    }

    private class OwnedClass
    {
        public void SomeMethod()
        {
            // Is anything from OwningClass available here?
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Anything "static" from the owning class is available in your nested class.

If you have an instance of the owning class in some method of the inner class, you may also access its private members.

Comment: I think the 'static' part is covered (better) by the second part - the nested class is a member too  and can access private members.

Comment: But anything `public static` is also accessible to other classes. Nothing to do with nesting.

Answer (score 3):

The only thing a nested class changes with respect to it's parent class is accessibility.  The nested class can access private members of the containing type.

Answer (score 1):

Not unless you passed in a reference of the OwningClass in the constuctor of the OwnedClass or through the SomeMethod of OwnedClass.

Enjoy!